# How to integrate a total derivative?

Tags: integration, derivatives

Suppose $f(x,y)=x y$

Then, its total derivative is
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{d}f&=x \mathbb{d}y+y \mathbb{d}x \\
\int\mathbb{d}f&= \int x \mathbb{d}y+ \int y \mathbb{d}x \tag{Integration}\\
f&=xy+yx +c\\
f&=2xy + c \\
f&=2xy \tag{suppose $c=0$} \\
\end{align}
$$

Why are we not getting back the same value of $f$?

Comment: Does this have any meaning to you? Or do the symbols just look nice when you put them together? You can only integrate both sides *with respect to a variable*... if you do that to both sides on line 1 I fail to see what you have in mind as being *that variable* line 2. $df$? $dx$? $dy$? If you're imagining that you're skipping steps, can you write them explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of path integrals, what you do when get $\int x \, dy + \int y \, dx = xy + yx$ is that you calculate the two integrals along different paths, the first along a "vertical" path and the other along a "horizontal" path. What you should to is do calculate both along the same path:

Let's take a linear path $\gamma$ from $(0,0)$ to $(x_0, y_0)$. This can be parameterized by $(x, y) = (t x_0, t y_0)$ where $t$ runs from $0$ to $1$. The integral then becomes
$$
\int_0^1 (t \, x_0)(dt \, y_0) + \int_0^1 (t \, y_0)(dt \, x_0) 
= x_0 y_0 \int_0^1 t \, dt + y_0 x_0 \int_0^1 t \, dt \\ 
= \frac12 x_0 y_0 + \frac12 x_0 y_0 = x_0 y_0
$$

In fact, in this case, since $x \, dy + y \, dx = d(xy)$ is an [exact differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential), any path between the two points will give the same result.

Answer (score 32):

That's not how it works. If you have

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y, \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = x $$

You can only integrate one variable at a time. For example integrate w.r.t $y$

$$ f(x,y) = \int x\ dy = xy + g(x) $$

Then taking the partial w.r.t $x$ of both sides
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = y + \frac{dg}{dx} $$

Thus $dg/dx = 0$ or $g(x) = c$. Then the final solution is

$$ f(x,y) = xy + c$$

which varies up to a constant, as expected.

---

If you prefer to use your notation, it looks something like

$$ df = x \ dy + y \ dx $$
$$ \int \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\ dy = \int x \ dy + \int y\frac{\partial x}{\partial y} dy $$

Since $x$ and $y$ are independent, $\partial x/\partial y = 0$ and you get
$$ f(x,y) = xy + g(x) $$

Note that the extra term is only constant w.r.t $y$ so we say it's some function of $x$

Answer (score 3):

$xy$ is not the antiderivative of $x \mathrm{d}y$, as you can see by checking the differential:

$$ \mathrm{d}(xy) = x \mathrm{d}y + y \mathrm{d}x$$

The right hand side can only equal $x \mathrm{d}y$ if we are in a dgenerate situation where $y \mathrm{d}x$ is identically zero.

In fact, $x \mathrm{d}y$ doesn't even *have* an antiderivative. A one-form that has an antiderivative must necessarily be a closed form: its differential must be zero. And that is not true for this form:

$$ \mathrm{d}\left( x \mathrm{d} y \right) = \mathrm{d}x \mathrm{d}y $$

The right hand side can only equal zero if there is a linear dependence between $\mathrm{d}x$ and $\mathrm{d}y$; e.g. if one is a smooth function of another, or both are smooth functions of a third variable.

---

Furthermore, in higher dimensions it is unusual to use the $\int$ sign for the antiderivative, because the antiderivative doesn't resemble any form of definite integral (e.g. a path integral).

One might use $\int$ for some sort of *partial* antiderivative, such as returning what the antiderivative would be under the premise that $x$ is being held constant. And, in fact, that is precisely the value you gave for $\int x \mathrm{d}y$.

But notions of partial antiderivative do not give the antiderivative of the form. (unless, of course, the actual problem satisfies the premise of the partial antiderivative; e.g. if $x$ really is a constant, so that $\mathrm{d}x=0$)

Answer (score 3):

*I'd have left this as a comment on Dylan's answer, but I don't have enough reputation for that!*

I'd just like to share [a very useful video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgHCy25hBJE) I watched after having wondered this exact same question (and made the exact same error). The answers here helped, but I still didn't have an intuitive understanding until I had watched this, so I thought I'd link it here for anyone in the future who was in my position.

As another aside; I was equally confused due to lacklustre approach many physics lecturers have in regard to mathematical accuracy. Often when a lecturer is faced with an equation like $\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t}=F$ they'll first multiply by $\mathrm{d}t$ and then integrate both sides, ie:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t}=F$$
$$\mathrm{d}P=F\mathrm{d}t$$
$$\int\mathrm{d}P = \int F\mathrm{d}t$$
$$P=\int F\mathrm{d}t$$

Now perhaps you can understand the approach of the Anon21. This example was performed by a lecturer of mine today! Of course, (as I have recently learnt) the correct way to perform this is as follows:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t}=F$$
$$\int \frac{\mathrm{d}P}{\mathrm{d}t} \mathrm{d}t = \int F \mathrm{d}t$$
$$P = \int F \mathrm{d}t$$

I'm not really sure why some lecturers choose to show the former, especially seeing as the second is both shorter and actually correct. You can see how this leads to confusion when students are faced with differential equations - like $\mathrm{d}t = x\mathrm{d}y + y\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: Imho the passing from $\frac{dP}{dt}=F$ to $dP=F\,dt$ is as good as your approach to cancel the $dt$ under an integral sign. When we solve ODEs by separation of variables we can always rigorise in the end our favourite method by checking that the solution solves the ODE. The point of this post is not this question. It has to do with exact/inexact differentials. Physicists as early as in the 19th century were aware of them when they did thermodynamics. See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4584665/949989).

Answer (score 0):

I made this observation (a long time ago) back in my BSc days.

I proposed that one has to make a `special sum`, where identical terms are not summed up, but remain the same.
In this case, we would have: $F = (xy) \bigoplus (yx) \bigoplus c = xy + c$.

The question remains whether this always works or not.

I guessed this was the case, so I came with this demonstration.

We let $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, furthermore let $F$ be given as $F(x,y) = f_1(x, y) + f_2(x) + f_3(y) + c_4$, with all $f_i:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ (in $\mathbb{R}^2$ we would have that $f_2$ is a curve in the XZ-plane swept along the Y-axis, and $f_3$ a curve in the YZ-plane swept along the X-axis, and the constant $c_4$ is the plane $z=c_4$.

So let's take the total derivative of $F$
\begin{eqnarray}
    \mathrm{d}F &=& \frac{\partial f_1(x,y)}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x 
      + \frac{\partial f_1(x,y)}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y
      + \frac{\partial f_2(x)}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x
      + \frac{\partial f_2(x)}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y
      + \frac{\partial f_3(y)}{\partial x} \mathrm{d}x
      + \frac{\partial f_3(y)}{\partial y} \mathrm{d}y
      + 0\nonumber\\
    &=& \left(
      \frac{\partial f_1(x,y)}{\partial x}
       +  \frac{\partial f_2(x)}{\partial x}\right) \mathrm{d}x
       +  \left(\frac{\partial f_1(x,y)}{\partial y} 
       +  \frac{\partial f_3(y)}{\partial y} \right) \mathrm{d}y
\end{eqnarray}

From this equation, and using the `special sum`:

\begin{eqnarray}
    \int \mathrm{d}F &=& \int\left[ \left(
      \frac{\partial f_1(x,y)}{\partial x}
       +  \frac{\partial f_2(x)}{\partial x}\right) \mathrm{d}x
       \bigoplus  \left(\frac{\partial f_1(x,y)}{\partial y} 
       +  \frac{\partial f_3(y)}{\partial y} \right) \mathrm{d}y\right]\nonumber\\
    F &=& \Big(f_1(x,y) + f_2(x)\Big) \bigoplus \Big(f_1(x,y) + f_3(y)\Big) + c\nonumber\\
      &=& f_1(x,y) + f_2(x) + f_3(y) + c
\end{eqnarray}

You can also check that this `special sum` also works for any number of variables, for example, we let $F:\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and write:
$F(x, y, z) =  f_1(x, y, z) + f_2(x, y) + f_3(x, z) + f_4(y, z) + f_5(x) + f_6(y) + f_7(z) + c_8 $ ... and the rest is left as an exercie.

For $F:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ you will have $2^n$ terms in the expression of $F(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, and the same logic applies.

$\mathbf{Theorem:}$
Given a differential equation $F = G(x,y) \mathrm{d}x + H(x,y) \mathrm{d}y$, satisfying the following equation (for total differential)

\begin{eqnarray}
 \partial G/\partial y &=& \partial H/\partial x
\end{eqnarray}

we have the following:
\begin{eqnarray}
 \int F &=& \int G(x,y)\mathrm{d}x \bigoplus \int H(x,y) \mathrm{d}y
\end{eqnarray}

this way you can save a few steps.