# Why is a multivariable function satisfying the following conditions exact?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I read this section in the book "Mathematics Methods for Physics and Engineering"

> Determining whether a differential containing many variable $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$
> exact is a simple extension of the above. A differential containing many variables can be written in general as
> $$df=\Sigma^n_{i=1}g_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)dx_i$$
> and the function will be exact if
> $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j}=\frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}$ for all pairs of i and n.

I can understand the situation when there are only two variables in the function, but when there are many variables, I am a bit confused about why this condition is already necessary  to prove that the function is exact, instead of requiring all partial derivatives of the function to be equal.

Answer (score 4):

- By definition, an [exact differential ***one form***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms)
  $$
  \omega=\sum^n_{i=1}g_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\,dx_i
  $$
  arises from a function, aka $0$-form, $f$ by exterior differentiation $\omega=df\,.$
- Saying that the differential $\omega$ is exact amounts to showing that the function $f$ exists. Writing the differential from the beginning as $df$ is therefore confusing.
- The reason for this confusion is imho that the authors Riley, Hobson & Bence are trying to avoid the language of differential forms and mention the above result without proof or reference.
- By the [Poincare lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_and_exact_differential_forms#Poincar%C3%A9_lemma) it is enough to show that $\omega$ is closed which means that
  $d\omega=0\,.$
- By the exterior differential calculus rules,
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d\omega&=\sum^n_{i,j=1} \partial_j g_i(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\,dx_j\wedge dx_i
  \end{eqnarray}
  which is zero because $\partial_j g_i$ is symmetric in $i,j$ and $dx_j\wedge dx_i$ is antisymmetric.
- In order that the Poincare lemma is applicable we need to assume that the domain of the $g_i$ functions is [simply connected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simply_connected_space).
- Examples of [inexact differentials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inexact_differential#First_law_of_thermodynamics) arise in Thermodynamics: change in heat $Q$ and change in work $W$ and are usually denoted by
  $\delta Q$ and $\delta W$ following Carl Gottfried Neumann. The first law of thermodynamics is then
  $$
  dU=\delta Q-\delta W
  $$
  where $U$ is the internal energy and has an exact differential.

Answer (score 0):

The author shouldn't write $df$ there. Suppose $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set. A one form is an object of the form
$$\omega = \sum_{i = 1}^{n}g_i(x)\,dx_i,$$
where each $g_i \in C^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$. The one-form $\omega$ is said to be exact if there exists a smooth function $f \in C^{\infty}(\Omega, \mathbb{R})$ such that
$$df := \sum_{i = 1}^{n}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i}dx_i = \omega.$$
The above equation is equivalent to
$$g_i = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \text{ for } i = 1, \dots, n.$$
Now if $\omega$ is exact, meaning that the above holds, then
$$\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_i \partial x_j} = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_j \partial x_i} = \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}.$$
So exactness implies $\frac{\partial g_i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial g_j}{\partial x_i}$ for $i, j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$. However, the converse is not true in general. It is true when $\Omega$ is simply connected though, which means roughly that any smooth closed curve in $\Omega$ is smoothly homotopic to a point through a family of closed curves.